# In android layouts what is the effect/meaning of layout_height="0dip"

Tags: android, android-layout

I've seen several examples that use
android:layout_height="0px" or "0dip" but i do not understand the impact of this. It seems that would make the layout 0 pixels tall. Is the value mitigated but some other factor like 'weight' or the height of any parent views?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yep you are right about the weight, when you want the width or height to be controlled by weight its convention to set that value to 0dip and let the weight control the actual value. Although I am pretty sure 0 is just arbitrary here you could put anything but putting 0 makes your intention more clear.

Comment: setting the `layout_width` or `layout_height` to `0px` or `0dip` is rather more for run-time performance rather than convention. Setting it to `0px` (or `0dip`) will skip the cpu cycles necessary for the initial initialization and the view's width/height will be adjust as required. In summary, the run-time will only have to calculate height/width once rather than 2 times...

Answer (score 13):

When using a LinearLayout if you set the `layout_weight` to a non-zero value and set the `layout_height` (or `layout_width`) to 0px or 0dip then the LinearLayout distributes any unassigned space along the appropriate axis based on the weights. So for example, if you look at the layout below the View with id *gestures_overlay* it has `layout_height` 0dip and `layout_weight` 1 so the parent LinearLayout stretches it to fill the available vertical space between the 2 surrounding LinearLayouts. If there was another View with the same 0dip `layout_height` and a `layout_weight` value then they would share the vertical space based on their weight values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"

            android:text="@string/prompt_gesture_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/gesture_name"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:maxLength="40"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gestures_overlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"

        android:gestureStrokeType="multiple" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done"

            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:enabled="false"

            android:onClick="addGesture"
            android:text="@string/button_done" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="cancelGesture"
            android:text="@string/button_discard" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of weight zero? owr instructor in android course ask this question . what is the usage of weight zero in android UI designing?

Answer (score 4):

A relevant example from the official developer docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html):

**Equally weighted children**

To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to "**0dp**" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view to "**0dp**" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight of each view to "1".

Answer (score 0):

When we have to assign **equal weight** to the different view in LINEAR LAYOUT 
then we assign either layout/width = 0dp(for horizontal orientation) or layout/height = 0dp(for vertical orientation) and set View /weight ==1 for every view inside that Linear Layout.

Advantage::::
   -- on assigning width or height to 0dp then it have no impact and due to weight==1 all the view occupies same space and covered the whole screen size.