# What does layout_height="0dp" mean?

Tags: android, android-layout

I looked at lot of places where layout_height="0dp" used. Can someone tell me what does it mean? I tried looking at android developer docs and did not find relevant information there.

Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986793/in-android-layouts-what-is-the-effect-meaning-of-layout-height-0dip)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out...it definitely helps..

Comment: Is "0dp" the same as "0dip" from the other question?

Comment: Yes, "dp" and "dip" are equivalent.  [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Answer (score 25):

Well, height or width when set to "0dp", are mostly used in combination with "weight". e.g. you want to fill all the available space for height:

```
android:layout_height = "0dp"
android:layout_weight = "1.0"
```