# Placing Two elements at the left of and at the right of parent relative layout in android xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

i want to two elements at the left side of relative layout and two elements at the right side of the same relative layout in android xml. i tried like below. it doesn't work.

My Xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/primary_color"
android:id="@+id/linear_parentPl"
tools:context=".PlayList">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_iconPl"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_ios_24"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/play_list"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_iconPl"
        android:textColor="@color/light_orange"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logout_text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/logout_iconPl"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/logout_text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logout_iconPl"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logoutrounded"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

could any body help me to achieve this?

my output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to drop the Relative-Layout and directly use the constraint layout.
Giving some constraints should do the trick to place an object on the right end.

```
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/xxx"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
```

where "@id/xxx" is the id of the left-side object.
If you have more than one left-sided objects, wrap them into another constraint-layout and give the constraint-layout an id to reference it.

Additionally there may also be a 0dp on witdh or height necessary, like:

```
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

This will fill up the empty space in either width or height (not usable on both).
Details at [What does layout_height="0dp" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975607/what-does-layout-height-0dp-mean)

Comment: i simply removed `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` in text view. now it works as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused about your problem. Your problem is not clear to me. But according to my understanding, the below image exactly matches your requirement as you want.

[image: Playlist Screen]

If it matches the requirements then I write the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.activity.PlayList">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/top_bar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_iconPl"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_ios_24" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back_iconPl"
            android:text="@string/play_list"
            android:textColor="@color/light_orange"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logout_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:text="@string/logout_text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logout_iconPl"
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logoutrounded" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Nothing you have to do it. Just copy the whole code and paste it to your **.xml** file.

Add this line to your **color.xml** file.

```
<color name="top_bar">#395856</color>
```

And click on the **run**.