# Android: Why equally weighted buttons having different widths?

Tags: android, android-layout

Consider the following code and the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ABCDE" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ABC" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

[image]

The buttons are given same `layout_weight`, but having different widths. Why they don't occupy same widths? What can I do to make them to have equal widths (without giving pixel values)?

Comment: change layout_witdh with 0dip on buttons, and see. It works for me

Comment: @Daler You might want to put that as an answer. ;)

Comment: @Daler It seems working, but what is the reason?

Comment: @DUKE Check out this link for the answer to your second question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986793/in-android-layouts-what-is-the-effect-meaning-of-layout-height-0dip

Comment: @Daler It works, thanks. If you put as an answer I will accept it. :-)

Comment: i did) with a lot of edits from prolink )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `layout_width` to `0dip` will fix the issue.

For more information regarding the reason why this works or the reason to use, check out this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986793/in-android-layouts-what-is-the-effect-meaning-of-layout-height-0dip).

Glad that it helped.

Comment: Just improving your answer. Taking out the not needed information and added an answer to his second question. If you feel like the edits were not useful, you can always revert them. My apologies, none of the edits took away from the answer you provided. It only improved your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `layout_width` to `0dip`, but will not be very good if the text is too long.