# How Can I make a android xml view as this

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I wanted to create an xml layout similiar to this, but my xml code didn't work out.

[image]

Here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" >

    <ImageButton
        android:name = "@+id/switchOriginDest"
        android:src="@drawable/switchorigdest"
        android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Origin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:hint="@string/mycurrentpos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Destination"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
        android:layout_below="@id/Origin"
        android:hint="@string/desthint"
        android:padding="6dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I have now is

[image]

**----------UPDATE------------**

Setting the layout_width of TextView to a fixed number solved the problem. However can anyone kindly answer some follow up questions from me?

1. isn't 0dp making the component automatically take up the remaining space. how come it didn't work in this case.
2. How can I make the red and green circle as shown in the example?

Comment: Can you show the current result you've got ? It can help to see where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this(Modify it as per your need):

**Using Linear Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:name="@+id/switchOriginDest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       >
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Origin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:hint="mycurrentpos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Destination"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="desthint"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:padding="6dip" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

hope it will help.

**Using Relative layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/switchOriginDest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Origin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switchOriginDest"
        android:hint="mycurrentpos"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Destination"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Origin"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/switchOriginDest"
        android:hint="desthint"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: People should learn to use RelativeLayout instead of nested LinearLayouts. It would be less heavy at runtime. He's solution should be better once fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The layout_width  set do 0dp is not clear in your example.  It's a good habit to set it if you use the weight to manage size, but your not setting any weight for your layout size.

try to use wrap_content or some fixed size and see if it helps :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp" //here it seems ok, since you set the weight to 1
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" >

    <ImageButton
        android:name = "@+id/switchOriginDest"
        android:src="@drawable/switchorigdest"
        android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_width = "50dp"  //since you src image is bigger than what you need to display, you can't rely on wrap content here ;)
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Origin"
        android:layout_width="200dp"  //lets try with this size.
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:hint="@string/mycurrentpos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Destination"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" //you probably want to align that on the bottom ?
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
        android:layout_below="@id/Origin"
        android:hint="@string/desthint"
        android:padding="6dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[More informations about using 0dp sizes here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986793/in-android-layouts-what-is-the-effect-meaning-of-layout-height-0dip)

Comment: I've adding a size to the image since, your src image seems bigger than the needed size.

Comment: yeah explicitly setting the width of TextView solved the problem, but I don't understand, isn't setting the width to 0dp make it automatically occupy the space remained?

Comment: No, setting to 0dip mean "the size will be managed by another criteria" its often used with the weight set to 1 and in most of case it makes it occupy the remaining space but that's what leads to misunderstanding.

Comment: In your case you can use 0dp and set alignRight to the parent (like you did) and align left to the ImageButton  (using android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchOriginDest")=> it will make it use the space between those two limits.