# Issue with layout weight in Android LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

The way my program works is that I take user input for 3 items, create a horizontal `LinearLayout` programmatically with those three items. Then place that `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` that is defined in XML.

User can keep adding these 3-item horizontal LLs to the bottom of the `RelativeLayout`, which acts as a list in this case.

I am specifying a weight in the `setLayoutParams` method for each `TextView` object

```
    TextView quantityText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    quantityText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    quantityText.setText("" + currentIngredientMeasurementQuantity);


    TextView typeText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    typeText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    typeText.setText(currentIngredientMeasurementType);


    TextView nameText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    nameText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4f));
    nameText.setText(currentIngredientName);


    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    ll.setId(View.generateViewId());

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ingredient_list_relativelayout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //Find last member of RelativeLayout
    View lastIngredient = (View) relativeLayout.getChildAt(totalIngredientQuantity - 1);

    relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastIngredient.getId());
    relativeParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);


    ll.addView(quantityText);
    ll.addView(typeText);
    ll.addView(nameText);

    relativeLayout.addView(ll, relativeParams);
```

The problem is, the `TextViews` aren't being displayed the way I'd like them to. I'd like each of the three items to line up vertically, like a proper list.

Instead, I get [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuD0K.jpg). You can see that the length of the strings is somehow affecting the way the layout is stored/displayed.

I know it's a big block of code, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Add a screenshot of the layout. Will be helpful.

Comment: why don't you try Weight

Comment: @KNeerajLal I have a screenshot of the layout in the post

Comment: @GrahamBewley check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `Gravity` to Left (or Start) on your `TextViews` before adding them to the `LinearLayout`, just like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams name_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
name_lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
nameText.setLayoutParams(name_lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Create a custom layout insteadof creating controls as dynamically

custom.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="90">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="text1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:text="text2"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:text="text3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Add this view in RelativeLayout

```
View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
relativeLayout.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `layout_width` property to `0` for `layout weight` property to work well. I made a couple to changes to your code to make it work well for me.

Try this,

```
private void addNewRow(float currentIngredientMeasurementQuantity, String currentIngredientMeasurementType, String currentIngredientName) {

    TextView quantityText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    quantityText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    quantityText.setText("" + currentIngredientMeasurementQuantity);

    TextView typeText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    typeText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    typeText.setText(currentIngredientMeasurementType);

    TextView nameText = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    nameText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4f));
    nameText.setText(currentIngredientName);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        ll.setId(View.generateViewId());
    } else {
        ll.setId(totalIngredientQuantity);
    }

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ingredient_list_relativelayout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    //Find last member of RelativeLayout
    View lastIngredient = (View) relativeLayout.getChildAt(totalIngredientQuantity - 1);

    if (lastIngredient != null) {
        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastIngredient.getId());
        relativeParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    ll.addView(quantityText);
    ll.addView(typeText);
    ll.addView(nameText);

    relativeLayout.addView(ll, relativeParams);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to tell your your `Textview`s to use all the available space they can get. So they will fill the whole `LinearLayout`.

Instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` use `MATCH_PARENT` or `FILL_PARENT`

In XML you could use 0dip like described here: [In android layouts what is the effect/meaning of layout_height="0dip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986793/in-android-layouts-what-is-the-effect-meaning-of-layout-height-0dip)

Another idea would be to use TableLayout or GridLayout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Have Fun