# How to make bottom navigation view stick to a position in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I tried Bottom Navigation View in android. But it is changing it's position based upon the fragment that i present above it. How to solve this issue ?

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.d.wordsearch.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        xmlns:design="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android.support.design"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context="com.d.wordsearch.HomeFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="@string/hint_search_field"
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word_search_button"
            android:text="@string/button_word_search"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            style="@style/ButtonAppearance"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/other_search_button"
            android:text="@string/button_other_search"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            style="@style/ButtonAppearance"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Just to check if this is happening, I added a few text views into one of the fragments.

fragment_preferences.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.d.wordsearch.PreferencesFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Preferences" />


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Preferences"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        />


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Preferences" />


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Preferences" />


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Preferences"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        />


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Preferences"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is what happens when I switch between fragments:

[Home Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aaGA.png)

[Preferences Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKBEK.png)

Comment: Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and keem bottom bar align paren bottom

Comment: Tried. Not helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set height of `FrameLayout` and `BottomNavigationView` to `0dp`

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

everything else seems fine.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986793/in-android-layouts-what-is-the-effect-meaning-of-layout-height-0dip) might give you more information.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong weight assign to your layout use this type, weight ratio should be 100% per screen then set weight 9 to **Framlayout** or use **RelativeLayout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.d.wordsearch.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        xmlns:design="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android.support.design"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

If use RelativeLayout than use this type

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content Container -->

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```